# can't access composite column from cassandra cli

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I'm trying to run a 'get' from the Cassandra CLI (using Cassandra 1.2) to take a look at a value involved with a specific row and column. When running list , I can see the row keys and column names/values  but when doing a get for one of the specific row and columns, I get a 'Value not found' error. The CF I am trying to query has a comparator of CompositeType(DateType, CompositeType(UTF8Type, Int32Type)), and doing something like

```
get CF['rowkey']['2014-01-01 00\\:00\\:00+0000:UTF8Type\\:2'];
```

yields no results, even though you can see from running

```
get CF['rowkey'];
```

that is a valid combination of row of column. What do I have to do to be able to query for this row and column with this comparator?

Column family information:

```
column_type = 'Standard'
Key validation class: UTF8Type
Cells sorted by: CompositeType(DateType, CompositeType(UTF8Type, Int32Type))
Compaction Strategy: LeveledCompactionStrategy
```

Comment: Since you're talking about the outdated cli can you tell us what version of cassandra you are using and what the table that stores the composite is structured like?

Comment: Updated with some more info.